# On the first page of the table (only the first event page), clicking switch doesn't change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

here is demo question [video](https://imgur.com/a/KtrHk46) (could watch it for better understanding)

**Problem: On the first page of event_webapi (only the first page), clicking the switch does not change**
The alarm page does not have this problem, and their codes are clearly the same

- Failed code for "event_webapi table"
  *(Click the switch switch "Selected_webapi" did not change)*

```
function modalTable_WEBAPI_event() {
  console.log("TABLE MODAL");
  const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
  var getData;
  var currentPage = 1;
  newValue = localStorage.getItem("newValue");

  var datatable_WEBAPI_event = $("#id_datatable_WEBAPI_event").DataTable({
    processing: true,
    lengthChange: false,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
      url: newValue + '/api/message/list',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
      },
      type: "POST", 
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: function(d) {
        d.search = d.search.value;
        console.log(d);
        return JSON.stringify(d);
      },
      dataSrc: function (response) {
        console.log("DATA MODAL TABLE", response.data);
        getData = response.data.map(obj => {
          let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
          result['isChanged'] = false; // Set a variable
          return result;
        });

        console.log('DATA CHANGE', getData);

        return getData;
      },
    },
    destroy: true,
    columns: [
      { data: "sf", title: "sf" },
      { data: "code", title: "code" },
      { data: "subcode", title: "subcode" },
      { data: "msgtext", title: "msgtext" },
      { data: "description", title: "description_webapi_event" },
      {
        data: null,
        title: "Alarm/Event Setting",
        render: function (data, type, row) {
          var switchId = 'customSwitch_' + row.id;
          var switchHTML = '<div class="custom-control custom-switch">';
          var isChecked = row.webapi ? 'checked' : '';
          switchHTML += '<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="webapi_' + switchId + '" ' + isChecked + '>';
          switchHTML += '<label class="custom-control-label" for="webapi_' + switchId + '">Selected_webapi</label>';
          switchHTML += '</div>';
          return switchHTML;
        },
        createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
          var switchId = 'customSwitch_' + rowData.id;
          var switchElement = $(td).find('#webapi_' + switchId);
          console.log("WEBAPI Element: ", switchElement);
          var isChecked = rowData.webapi ? 'checked' : '';
          switchElement.change(function () {
            console.log("WEBAPI switchId: ", switchId);
            console.log("WEBAPI isChecked: ", isChecked);
            console.log("WEBAPI switchElement: ", switchElement);

            // Compare old data with new data to detect changes
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
              rowData.webapi = true;
              rowData.isChanged = true;
            } else {
              rowData.webapi = false;
              rowData.isChanged = true;
            }
            var selectedRows = datatable_WEBAPI_event.rows({ selected: true }).data();
            console.log("Selected Rows >>>>>", selectedRows);
            webapi_server.data = selectedRows.map(function (row) {
              return { id: row.id, enable: row.webapi };
            });
            webapi_server.length = webapi_server.data.length;
            webapi_server.server = "webapi";
            console.log("Selected Rows:", webapi_server);
            var changedData = getData.filter(item => item.isChanged == true);
            console.log("Changed Data:", changedData);

            console.log("changedData webapi", changedData);

            // Convert changedData to the required format
            var changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi_0 = changedData.map(item => ({
              id: item.id,
              enable: item.webapi
            }));
            console.log("changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi_0", changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi_0);

            // Add the converted data to the target object
            changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi = {
              draw: 1,
              length: changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi_0.length,
              server: "webapi",
              data: changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi_0
            };
            console.log("changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi:", changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi);
          });
        },
      }
    ]
  });

  // Initialize the tabs in the WEBAPI modal
  $('#webapiTabs a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
  });

  // Filter out data where "sf" is "S05F01"
  datatable_WEBAPI_event.column(0).search('S06F11').draw();

  setTimeout(function() {
    currentPage = datatable_WEBAPI_event.page.info().page;
    console.log("Current Page:", currentPage);
    datatable_WEBAPI_event.ajax.reload(function(){
      datatable_WEBAPI_event.page(currentPage).draw('page');
    }, false);
  }, 60000);
}
```

- There is no problem with the alarm page, I'm confuse cause the code they're using is the same
  *(and event first page switch cannot switch when clicked )*

```
function modalTable_WEBAPI_event() {
  console.log("TABLE MODAL");
  const getToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
  var getData;
  var currentPage = 1;
  newValue = localStorage.getItem("newValue");

  var datatable_WEBAPI_event = $("#id_datatable_WEBAPI_event").DataTable({
    processing: true,
    lengthChange: false,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
      url: newValue + '/api/message/list',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getToken
      },
      type: "POST", 
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: function(d) {
        d.search = d.search.value;
        console.log(d);
        return JSON.stringify(d);
      },
      dataSrc: function (response) {
        console.log("DATA MODAL TABLE", response.data);
        getData = response.data.map(obj => {
          let result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
          result['isChanged'] = false; // Set a variable
          return result;
        });

        console.log('DATA CHANGE', getData);

        return getData;
      },
    },
    destroy: true,
    columns: [
      { data: "sf", title: "sf" },
      { data: "code", title: "code" },
      { data: "subcode", title: "subcode" },
      { data: "msgtext", title: "msgtext" },
      { data: "description", title: "description_webapi_event" },
      {
        data: null,
        title: "Alarm/Event Setting",
        render: function (data, type, row) {
          var switchId = 'customSwitch_' + row.id;
          var switchHTML = '<div class="custom-control custom-switch">';
          var isChecked = row.webapi ? 'checked' : '';
          switchHTML += '<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="webapi_' + switchId + '" ' + isChecked + '>';
          switchHTML += '<label class="custom-control-label" for="webapi_' + switchId + '">Selected_webapi</label>';
          switchHTML += '</div>';
          return switchHTML;
        },
        createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
          var switchId = 'customSwitch_' + rowData.id;
          var switchElement = $(td).find('#webapi_' + switchId);
          console.log("WEBAPI Element: ", switchElement);
          var isChecked = rowData.webapi ? 'checked' : '';
          switchElement.change(function () {
            console.log("WEBAPI switchId: ", switchId);
            console.log("WEBAPI isChecked: ", isChecked);
            console.log("WEBAPI switchElement: ", switchElement);

            // Compare old data with new data to detect changes
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
              rowData.webapi = true;
              rowData.isChanged = true;
            } else {
              rowData.webapi = false;
              rowData.isChanged = true;
            }
            var selectedRows = datatable_WEBAPI_event.rows({ selected: true }).data();
            console.log("Selected Rows >>>>>", selectedRows);
            webapi_server.data = selectedRows.map(function (row) {
              return { id: row.id, enable: row.webapi };
            });
            webapi_server.length = webapi_server.data.length;
            webapi_server.server = "webapi";
            console.log("Selected Rows:", webapi_server);
            var changedData = getData.filter(item => item.isChanged == true);
            console.log("Changed Data:", changedData);

            console.log("changedData webapi", changedData);

            // Convert changedData to the required format
            var changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi_0 = changedData.map(item => ({
              id: item.id,
              enable: item.webapi
            }));
            console.log("changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi_0", changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi_0);

            // Add the converted data to the target object
            changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi = {
              draw: 1,
              length: changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi_0.length,
              server: "webapi",
              data: changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi_0
            };
            console.log("changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi:", changedData_to_jsonAPI_webapi);
          });
        },
      }
    ]
  });

  // Initialize the tabs in the WEBAPI modal
  $('#webapiTabs a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
  });

  // Filter out data where "sf" is "S05F01"
  datatable_WEBAPI_event.column(0).search('S06F11').draw();

  setTimeout(function() {
    currentPage = datatable_WEBAPI_event.page.info().page;
    console.log("Current Page:", currentPage);
    datatable_WEBAPI_event.ajax.reload(function(){
      datatable_WEBAPI_event.page(currentPage).draw('page');
    }, false);
  }, 60000);
}
```